# How do I configure proxy credentials for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, proxy, proxy-authentication

I have searched on MSDN, but i could not find how to configure username and password for proxy on Visual Studio 2012 config file.
I found this:

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
 <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://<yourproxy:port#>"/>
</defaultProxy>
```

Is there a way to specify username and password?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer (the above works for [me](http://taeguk.co.uk/blog/working-in-visual-studio-behind-the-firewall/)), but there is a local proxy called [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) you can use if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

Set the proxy in Internet Explorer (Tools/Internet Options/Connections/LAN Settings/Proxy server) and save the credential for the Proxy in the Credential Store (`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`).
Note that while setting the proxy in IE, the Advanced button allows you to control which URL goes through the proxy and which not.

Absolutely no need to touch Visual Studio config file.